# Microsoft visual studio auto complete selection problem

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, select, autocomplete

when i am coding visual studio do not select best value.

if you look this image you will understand what i mean

[image: http://img252.imageshack.us/img252/4186/problemm.png]

microsoft visual studio 2010

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You are in IntelliSense Suggestion Mode.  Press CTRL + ALT + SPACE and that should put you back in Completion Mode.  You can find out more here:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zainnab/archive/2010/01/22/intellisense-suggestion-mode-vstipedit0012.aspx

Comment: Thank you! It was really annoying to restart VS to get it work.